# Webscraping - with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to beautifulsoup and I am having trouble using it on basketball reference. I am trying to store the entire dataframe of the Advanced stats into a pandas dataframe, but I cannot even select it. Here is my code so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url='http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/ATL/2016.html'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.findAll('table',attrs={'id': 'advanced'})
```

I see the html of what I need after selecting advanced from the code above, but I cannot actually parse and pull the data.

Answer (score 0):

Find the `table` element and let the [`read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) do the parsing and dataframe initializing job:

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'advanced'})

df = pd.read_html(str(table))
print(df)  # prints a dataframe with 15 rows x 27 columns
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am getting an 'ImportError: html5lib not found, please install it' error. However I install and I import it and still get this error. What should I do?

Comment: @PippensPips you may either need to install `html5lib`: `pip3 install html5lib` or try setting the parser to `bs4`: `df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(table)), flavor="bs4")`.

Comment: None of those solutions work. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @PippensPips I don't know your setup. You just need to install `html5lib` module to the same python environment you are executing your script in. Apparently, you have already somehow installed `BeautifulSoup` and `pandas` - it is absolutely the same way with `html5lib`.